# Reference actual object or just the object Id?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, design-patterns

I have this problem of confusing when to include the entire object as a property of another object, or just its ID.  It seems that if I include the entire object, the calls to load the containing object will unnecessarily also load the included object when I probably only need references.  What is propert approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally always refer to another object.

Many ORM technologies have the idea of "proxies" and "lazy loading", meaning, unless you reference the object, it won't load it.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to include the object itself, since one object actually has a relationship with another actual object -- the object ID is just an implementation detail.  To deal with the problem of unnecessary calls, look into "[lazy loading](http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/408/lazy-loading/)".

Answer (score 2):

1. Only include the other object if you need the details.
2. in MVC use a ViewModel ideally and not your entities. Your ViewModel contains only what it needs, so for example OrderEditViewModel would contain a customerid unless you want to display the custom name, in that case you would include the fields from customer. Some people recomend you flatten out your objects to a view model, so you dont have OrderEditViewModel.Customer.CustomerId but instead ORderEditViewModel.CustomerId.  Automapper can help you do this (As well as valueinjecter - note the spelling)
3. If you must include an ID ensure when you save back to the database your update include a clause to say 'where id=@customerId and (logic here to ensure your user actually has access to that customerid and root object)

I have mvcsecurity.codeplex.com to help encrypt record ids on a web page to prevent against tampering as well (it helps but you should still have something in your query to prevent field tampering so an attacker cant add someone else's customer id for example_)

I go more into parameter tampering in MVC here if anyone is interested:
http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/Courses/TableOfContents?courseName=hack-proofing-dotnet-app

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to always think about the design and not about performance. Performance can be tweaked but design can't. So, if the two objects have that kind of a relationship where Aggregation/Composition is required, you should do that.

But, if your containing object only has to deal with the ID (for e.g. passing it to a different object which processes the ID to do something) then you can keep the ID field only. No need to expose the whole object (but make sure that your containing object does not need to know anything about the other object.).